# sed command in make file with hard coded $

Tags: linux, sed, makefile, special-characters, quoting

I have a sed command in my makefile like following ,purpose of the command is, it should replace string "listen $address" to "",but as a result it is replacing "listen $address" to "$address"

```
sed -i -e "s/listen $$address//" file.txt
```

Please suggest any solution.
I have checked many posts but there $ is used as regex variable ,in my case it needs to be treated as hardcoded string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose your sed command in single quotes to avoid [variable expansion within double quotes](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting):

```
sed -e -i 's/listen $address//' file
```

You can use double quotes though by escaping the `$`:

```
sed -e -i "s/listen \$address//" file
```

Comment: I will keep $address like this only?no need of $$ ?

Comment: No need of `$$`.

Comment: I have tested with $ and $$, it will require $$ but keeping in single quotes solved the problem.sed -e -i 's/listen $$address//' file   .Thanks